# Unable to insert CheckBox in a pdf using jsPdf

Tags: jspdf

I am fallowing the link bellow,
http://fiddle.jshell.net/NishitDhakar/ugD5L/

I am able to create tables on pdf, but when I include checkbox, the checkbox is not printing on the pdf.

Any help ?